# Android Studio connect with existing SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

i have one application with SQLite database and then i create another application that can connect to the database that i created one, my question is, is it possible connect the existing database without copying the existing once ? if possible can any one give me a sample code to connect my existing database . the name of my database is "SEIS" and the Table is Proinfo .

Comment: have you read `SQLiteDatabase` docs?

Answer (score 0):

By default, each app's files are private to the app.

You could tell Android that your two apps should get permission to access each other's files by setting the [`sharedUserId` attribute](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#userid) for both and signing them with the same signature, but the 'official' way to give other apps access to your data is to create a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible through the use of content providers. According to the documentation:

> A content provider manages access to a central repository of data. A provider is part of an Android application, which often provides its own UI for working with the data. However, content providers are **primarily** intended to be used by **other applications**, which access the provider using a provider client object.

I suggest you read the following articles:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_content_providers.htm